# How to get combined lists from two list using scala?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have two lists

```
val list1 = List((List("AAA"),"B1","C1"),(List("BBB"),"B2","C2"))
val list2 = List(("AAA",List("a","b","c")),("BBB",List("c","d","e")))
```

I want to match first element from `list2` with first element of `list1` and get combined list.
I want output as -

```
List((List("AAA"),"B1","C1",List("a","b","c")))
```

How to get above output using Scala??

Comment: list2 isn't a valid list; perhaps you could fix that and we can go from there? Specifically, those square brackets make no sense in that context.

Comment: Can you please see my edit now..

Comment: Could you provide more examples or rephrase what you want? "first element from list2 with first element of list1 and get combined list" will be List((List("AAA"),"B1","C1"), ("AAA",List("a","b","c"))) and not the list you gave.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with:

```
scala> val l1 = List((List("AAA"),"B1","C1"),(List("BBB"),"B2","C2"))
l1: List[(List[String], String, String)] = List((List(AAA),B1,C1), (List(BBB),B2,C2))

scala> val l2 = List((List("AAA"), List("a", "b", "c")), (List("BBB"), List("c", "d", "e")))
l2: List[(String, List[String])] = List((AAA,List(a, b, c)), (BBB,List(c, d, e)))

scala>  l1.collectFirst {
     |    case tp => l2.find(tp2 => tp2._1.head == tp._1.head).map(founded => (tp._1, tp._2, tp._3, founded._2))
     |  }.flatten
res2: Option[(List[String], String, String, List[String])] = Some((List(AAA),B1,C1,List(a, b, c)))
```

You can use `collectFirst` to filter values you don't want and on every tuple you use `find` on the second list and map it into the tuple you want.

A couple of notes, this is horrible, I don't know how you got with a `Tuple4` in the first place, I personally hate all that `tp._*` notation, it's hard to read, think about using case classes to wrap all that into some more manageable structure, second I had to use `.head` which in case of empty list will throw an exception so you may want to do some checking before that, but as I said, I would completely review my code and avoid spending time working on some flawed architecture in the first place.

Comment: Second list is slightly different from your second list

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you wanted only the first match, you can use `collectFirst` instead of `collect`

Comment: I'd echo Ende's suggestion of getting the original data into more sensible data structures.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [zip](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List) to combine both the list

```
val list1 = List((List("AAA"),"B1","C1"),(List("BBB"),"B2","C2"))
val list2 = List(("AAA",List("a","b","c")),("BBB",List("c","d","e")))

val combinedList = (list1 zip list2) 
combinedList.head will give you the desired result
```

It will give the combined list from which you can get the first element